# Получить данные от бота в телеграм

Tags: php, json, бот

Всем привет, пытаюсь получить данные от бота телеграмм

Для начала зарегистрировал бота тут:

https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=https://myDomain.com/telegrambot.php

в ответ получил: {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}

ssl сертификат выдан для *.myDomain.com от компании Go Daddy

Но при выполнении кода:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$log = print_r($data, true);
file_put_contents('./telegram.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

в telegram.txt получаю:
Array
(
)

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посмотреть инфо о статусе веб хука можно использовать метод getWebhookInfo.
Если сертификат самоподписанный или сертификат Let's Encrypt, то в форме загрузки сертификата нужно использовать @.
Пример:

```
curl -F "url=https://your_domain.combot-script.php" -F "certificate=@/path/to/certificate.crt" https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setWebhook
```